# Is there a Maven or Yum or Chocolatey equivalent for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a Maven, Yum or Chocolatey equivalent for PowerShell?

I'm looking for an easy to use repository of off the shelf modules that I can install from a web repository and then then import for use in my custom scripts.

I remember finding something a few weeks ago but my google skills have failed me in re-locating it. Hopefully this question and answer will provide a quick reference for folks in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell v5 provides the `Install-Module` cmdlet.  Here is the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn807162.aspx) for the usage.  And here is the [Module gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).  There is also [PsGet](https://github.com/psget/psget/) which will work for earlier versions of PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell 5 / WMF5 there's PowerShellGet and OneGet.

You can use commands bundled; like Install-Module and Install-package (or for uninstalling with respective uninstall functions).

Install-Package supports different packageproviders, whereas chocolatey is one of them. You can also create your own custom package providers for e.g. local usage or custom usage.

Example (assuming you have the chocolatey packageprovider installed), install chrome:

```
Get-package chrome -providername chocolatey|install-package
```

Example of installing powershell module:

```
Get-module posh-ssh|install-module -scope CurrentUser
```

For more information about the new package management system you can read a more detailed blog here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2014/10/06/package-management-for-powershell-modules-with-powershellget/